# How to put a box and its label in the same row? (shiny package)

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny, say i am using `textInput`, the field/box is always shown underneath the label. Is there a way that I can force them to be in the same row?

ie, `Label: BOX`

instead of

```
Label:

Box
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a very old question but thought answering it might be useful for someone who stumbles across this.

Adding this css helps to achieve label next to the inputs

```
tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", "label{ display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; } .form-group { display: table-row;}")
    )
```

Here is an example app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(

    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", "label{ display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; } .form-group { display: table-row;}")
    ),

    textInput(inputId = "txtInp", label = "Label:"),
    numericInput(inputId = "numInp", label = "Label:", value = 0)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The output of the app is as follows:

[image]

**EDIT:**
To address the **@fiftace's** comments of applying it only to a single input I have wrapped the input in a div with an id and modified the css to be applied to only that ID as follows:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(

    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", "#inline label{ display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; } 
                #inline .form-group { display: table-row;}")
    ),

    tags$div(id = "inline", textInput(inputId = "txtInp", label = "Label:")),
    numericInput(inputId = "numInp", label = "Label:", value = 0)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With this your output looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: your solution is the best on SO :) How do you make it apply to a single input (so the rest are unchanged)?

Comment: @fifthace , you could give IDs instead of using `label` and .`form-group`, that way it would only apply to that particular element.

Comment: Hmm, in your example, if I add an id in front label and .form-group class, it doesn't work. I.e. tags$style(type="text/css", "#txtInp label{ display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; } #txtInp.form-group { display: table-row;}"). What am I don't wrong here?

Comment: @fifthace, you can have a look at the edited part of the code. If you want to apply it to more than one input you could use `class` attribute instead of `id` attribute. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I can't quite get the class to work (replacing #inline with .my_inline_class and then having divs with class=my_inline_class didn't work). To try and clarify the issue, I made a new question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588582/box-and-input-inline-in-shiny-but-only-for-some-inputs); although I'll delete it if that is bad etiquette.

Comment: Thank you @SBista. This solution does not work with a `sliderInput()`. The slide is collapsed. Do you know what we should change?
`tags$div(id = "inline", 
           sliderInput(inputId = "slid", label = "label on top (default)", min = 0, value = 50, step = 1, max = 100)
  ),
  sliderInput(inputId = "slid2", label = "label inline desired", min = 0, value = 50, step = 1, max = 100)`

Answer (score 4):

Take at the look at the HTML output from fileInput, e.g.

```
fileInput("myfile", "Normal Label")
```

The HTML it generates is:

```
<label>Normal Label</label>
<input id="myfile" type="file"/>
<div id="myfile_progress" class="progress progress-striped active shiny-file-input-progress">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <label></label>
</div>
```

The label element has a line break by default. You need to change the CSS to get rid of that, i.e. you need to add something like

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  tags$head(    
    tags$style("label {display:inline;}")
  ),
  fileInput("myfile", "Inline Label")
))
```

This will of course effect all label elements, not just this one. If you only want to modify this one you need to include the HTML code directly in your app. You can do this by using the HTML function (note the additional CSS statement).

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  HTML('
  <label style="display: inline;">Inline Label</label>
    <input id="myfile" type="file"/>
    <div id="myfile_progress" class="progress progress-striped active shiny-file-input-progress">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <label></label>
    </div>
')
))
```

Comment: I am confused -- the OP never mentioned anything about a fileInput object. What does this have to do with making the textInput label inline?