# r shiny call css file

Tags: css, r, shiny, reference

The example is from [Box and input inline in Shiny, but only for some inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588582/box-and-input-inline-in-shiny-but-only-for-some-inputs).
I would like to create a css file. How looks a css file of this piece of code?

```
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", ".inline label{ display: table-cell; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; } 
                 .inline .form-group{display: table-row;}")
      )
```

and is this reference correct?

```
  tags$head(
tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "mycss.css")
```

),

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS file `mycss.css` would be

```css
.inline label {
  display: table-cell; 
  text-align: left; 
  vertical-align: middle;
} 
.inline .form-group { 
  display: table-row;
}
```

To include it in the app, put it in the **www** subfolder of the app, and write the following code in the UI:

```r
tags$head(
  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "mycss.css")
)
```

Alternatively, you can use `includeCSS`. This doesn't require to put the CSS file in the **www** subfolder. See `?includeCSS` for more info.

Comment: Thank you. That's it!