# how to make the radio buttons "side by side" in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, radio-button

I am trying to create a shiny app that contains a series of double-radio-button questions. The relevant codes are as below:

```
fluidRow(column(12, align='center',h4(tags$style(HTML(".radio-inline {margin-right: 200px;}"))), radioButtons("MPL1",label="",choiceNames=c("(60, 0; 12, 1)","(56, 0; 48, 1)"), choiceValues=c(0,1),selected= character(0),inline=T))),
```

It works, but I am stuck with adjusting the locations of the buttons. As the below figure shows, the default setting always puts the button at the left-hand side of its label, while I am trying to put the buttons against each other.

[image]

Could you please tell me how to achieve my expectation? Besides, it would be very lovely if you could tell me how I can systematically study css setting. I am eager to be an expert in making shiny apps. Thank you very much.

Best,
J

Comment: I'm not sure how to make this specific change, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850483/how-to-put-a-box-and-its-label-in-the-same-row-shiny-package/45299050

As far as learning css, the codecademy HTML/css tutorial was really helpful for me. You can do a one week free trial, and the tutorial took me a day or two to complete. https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-css

Comment: @Slim Thank you for your quick response. I will look at the materials you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I added two more rules to make this happen.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(12, align='center', 
            tags$style(HTML(
                "
                .radio-inline {margin-right: 200px;}
                .radio-inline:nth-of-type(odd) > span {
                    padding-right: 25px;
                }
                .radio-inline:nth-of-type(odd) > input {
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0;
                }
                "
            )), 
            radioButtons(
                "MPL1", label="", 
                choiceNames=c("(60, 0; 12, 1)","(56, 0; 48, 1)"), 
                choiceValues=c(0,1), 
                selected= character(0),
                inline=TRUE
            )
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

To learn CSS, use [W3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

Comment: Hi Lz100, thanks for your helpful response, and sorry for the late reply. I will have a look at the website you suggest. Have a good day!