# Align radio buttons

Tags: shiny, radio-button, alignment

This is trivial, I have no doubt, but I can not figure it out.
The question is an off-spin of the question [69760260](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69760260/how-to-make-the-radio-buttons-side-by-side-in-shiny). 
I am trying to align two sets of radio buttons.

```
    library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(tags$style(HTML(
    "
    .radio-inline {
      margin-right: 50px;
    }
    .radio-inline:nth-of-type(odd) > span {
      padding-right: 25px;
    }
    .radio-inline:nth-of-type(odd) > input {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }
    "
    )),
    radioButtons(
      "MPL1", label="Label 1", 
      choiceNames=c("yes","no"), 
      choiceValues=c(0,1), 
      selected= character(0),
      inline=TRUE
    ),
    radioButtons(
      "MPL2", label="Label 2", 
      choiceNames=c("(lorem yes)","(ipsum yes)"), 
      choiceValues=c(0,1), 
      selected= character(0),
      inline=TRUE
    )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I am getting is this: 
[image]

Whereas I would like to have this: 
[image]

Any help will be apprecited!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(tags$style(HTML(
  "
    #MPL1 {
      padding-left: 50px;
    }
    .radio-inline {
      margin-right: 50px;
    }
    .radio-inline:nth-of-type(odd) > span {
      padding-right: 25px;
    }
    .radio-inline:nth-of-type(odd) > input {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }
    "
)),
```

[image: output]

Comment: It actually doesnt work. Maybe in some browsers. Plus with multiple radioButtons it is lots if trial-and-error. Actually the most desired would be to have right aligned labels on the left and then aligned buttons, I am actually surprised that  there is nothing like that in CSS...